# How to achieve Hibernate @Any in Grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Does Grails somehow support Hibernates @Any annotation? I would like to know if and how.

I can achieve @Any by doing something like:

```
class A {
  String entityClass
  Long entityId // yes, only support type Long id's

  // dynamically load class (e.g. B), then call B.get(entityId)
}
```

But I'd like to do it more elegantly.

[Eyal Lupu's blog about Hibernate @Any](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_the_any_annotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since GORM is build on top of Hibernate, you can create a java class with the Hibernate annotations that will be mapped as a domain class.

There's a [section](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html) in the docs that cover this integration. Basically you need the configuration xml for hibernate (`hibernate.cfg.xml`) and create your class under `./src/java`.

Also, the dynamic GORM methods like `findAll()`, `get()`, `list()` and so on, will be available to your classes.

Comment: Would've like to keep it "all groovy", but apparently there's no such option.